# How ColdFusion exception and 404 errors should be handled?

Tags: exception, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Today I was designing the error handling statergy for a new website. I have gone through all the docs for ColdFusion Excepiton
handling.

Now I have some doubts.

What the best solution for handling 404 errors?

1. Using `onMissingTemplate()` method
2. `Sitewide Missing Template` option(CFAdmin)
3. `IIS custom 404 error handler`.

What is the best solution for exception handling?

1. What should I use for error logging `onError()` method or `Site-Wide Error handler`? Is there any significant difference between 
   these two?
2. Do I need to use try/catch block for each and every query that I write?

Because there are some queries where I am sure the query will only fail when the database will fail. So if the database fails ,there is no meaning process the page further using try/catch. What should I do in these situations?

I know this question looks bit subjective , but I can not find a better place than StackOverflow for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For handling **404's,** its better to handle it at webserver level.

For **Sitewide Missing Template**, you can specify the same in CF Admin. Ensure that the Sitewide error handler file location, should be relative to CF webroot and not webserver root. The dependent files may be put at the webserver.

Please refer to http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/onmissingtemplate, for IIS **custom 404 error handler**. This recent blog post has a detailed description of 404 and error handling.

Comment: Could you please explain me in which situation we should use "onMissingTemplate()" method in Application.cfc?

Comment: What is the exact difference between including a 404.cfm inside `onMissingTemplate()` method and specifying 404.cfm  as site wide missing template in `CFAdmin`? Does both server for the same purpose?

Comment: _onMissingTemplate()_ is only specific for 404, however, _Site-wide Error Handler_ is used when ColdFusion encounters an error while processing a request.

Comment: Yes I understand . But I was asking about difference between `onMissingTemplate()` and `Missing Template Handler` option in CFAdmin ? not the `Site-wide Error Handler `

Comment: Both of them are same.

Comment: They are not the same because one can have multiple applications running on a single CF instance. The application-specific `onMissingTemplate()` method takes precedence over the CF Admin `Missing Template Handler`. The latter fires if there isn't an application-specific `onMissingTemplate()`.

Comment: Let me rephrase it then. In terms of functionality, both are same. Obviously, if a function is specified inside Application.cfc, then it will have precedence. onMissingTemplate() can be used for multiple application and Missing Template Handler in CF Admin is specific to that particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you should use all three.

1. `onMissingTemplate()` is application-specific (remember that you can have multiple applications on a single CF instance).
2. `Missing Template Handler` is CF-instance specific.
3. `IIS custom 404 error handler` works for non-CF files (e.g., `.htm`, `.html`, etc.). You can still, of course, specify a CF template as the custom error handler.

FYI, the application-specific `onMissingTemplate()` method takes precedence over the CF Admin `Missing Template Handler`. The latter fires if there isn't an application-specific `onMissingTemplate()`.

As far as exception handling is concerned, that is going to depend on a number of factors, but again a multi-layered approach is good.